# License information for this component not found. you do not have appropriotate permisson to use this functionality in designer environment

Tags: vb6, ocx

I have an old Legacy Application Developed in VB 6.0. They used some 3rd Party controls using IGSplash40.OCX,PVCalendar9.OCX etc..The code works fine in one server.
They have installed Infragistics NetAdvantage 2004 Vol.1 tool to use those controls in VB Application. Now I have to move the application to another computer.
When I open the application especially forms..It says unable to load xxxform.refer logs for details and while running also It says 'License information for this component not foud. you do not have appropriotate permisson to use this functionality in designer environment'.

Also, I collected those ocx files from another server and tried to run my application.
How to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

The developer package for controls normally includes not only the OCXs and DLLs involved, and not only the documentation, but an installer that puts the libraries, docs, and any necessary design-time licenses in place and registers them.

If you find yourself copying such files in place and manually registering them you're likely to fail unless you have some freeware library.

Even freeware libraries should come with a proper set of docs, a DEP file, and dev machine install package to put everything in place.  Merge modules are a nice thing to offer as well.  Sadly most freeware authors are generous if they offer a *readme file*.

There is more to the ecosystem of an OCX than just the OCX file itself.

The only fix is to replace these controls with controls that you do have licenses for, buy alternatives, or try to contact the original vendor about supplying a replacement install package or acquiring a new license and new package.

Comment: In case that the licenses exists and you still get the error, it indicates that the control is missing one ore more dependencies. The error message will be the same in both cases.

Comment: I'm not saying that can't happen but there is a separate exception for just such cases.  This exception is pretty explicit, and also fits the described scenario of trying to hack a dev environment together.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7 you will find the usual .ocx files in the folder Windows\SysWOW64. In that folder there are a number of .srg files that seem to be the corresponding licenses. My problem was with richtx32.ocx and I had to open the corresponding RICHTEXT.SRG file, and create in the registry the corresponding key and introduce the license string manually.